# SockJS-Erlang and Yaws Webserver

Tags: websocket, erlang, sockjs, yaws

Thanks in advance but can anyone provide some guidance how I would use sockjs-erlang together with the Yaws Web Server. I have found some material on sockjs and cowboy but none on Yaws.

Thanks

Comment: This may interest you: http://yaws.hyber.org/websockets.yaws

Comment: Thanks, I am aware of Yaws' websockets. But, I want to use RabbitMq with websockets, not AMQP and it appears that a SockJS Rabbit plugin is the way to go. My Development stack is ExtJS on desktop, SenchaTouch on mobile; with distant distributed Erlang/OTP App Servers, Mnesia DBs, Yaws Webservers & RabbitMQ over websocket for low-latency pub-sub to frontends from OTP App Servers. Will replicate data via RabbitMq Shovelling/ Federation. I could use other options eg Riak as DB & Cowboy as webserver but have preferred Erlang/Mnesia/Yaws/Rabbit as strategic platform and Sencha libraries on clients.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the yaws websocket documentation:

http://yaws.hyber.org/websockets.yaws

Also checkout this project:

https://github.com/sockjs/sockjs-erlang

sockjs-erlang works with Cowboy but it could be ported to Yaws. I didn't dig through the codebase, but assuming they aren't making many calls Cowboy, it should be relatively straightforward to port the library.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for this. If anyone has ported sockjs-erlang to work with Yaws kindly post. If after a few weeks there are no positive reponses to this last question then I will attempt to design and implement this and share.